# Difference between 1000 and 1000.0 in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

Here I have a code that sets fireDate of an NSTimer object.

```
-(void)TimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer{
    long startTime=random()%1500+500;
    [timer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:startTime/1000.0]];
    [controller startCarFromLane:self];
}
```

In the above code when I write :startTime/1000.0 I get the timer fired after fairly enough amount of time. But if I change it to :startTime/1000 (without .0) timer's next fireDate is different from the case above,the timer fires more frequently . I know that dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow method expects an NSTimeInterval which is a typedef of double. But can't I write 10.0 as just 10? How can the .0 have an impact on the value?

Comment: You could, instead, write `(float) 1000`, but if you're lazy like me you'll go for the shorter `1000.0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you simply write 1000, the compiler implies an integer type. Thus, when dividing two integers (startTime is a long and 1000 is probably an int), it would be integer division, resulting in the floor of the accurate (exact) ration. E. g., 2500 / 1000 will be 2. However, when you write 1000 as 1000.0, the compiler emits a float. An integer divided by a float results in a float, so 2500 / 1000.0 will be 2.5, as expected. Basically that's why you get shorter intervals when simply using an integer. (In other words, it's the fact that integer division throws away the modulo divided by the divisor).

Comment: Yeah, I'd definitely forgotten about the fact that if either of the devisor or the devidend is a float then the result will be a floating point number. If both sides are integers then the result is integer,so that the part right to the floating point is truncated. Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

Since integer/long division drops the decimal part altogether, and because your `startTime` is declared as `long`, the result of `startTime/1000` is an integer. The result of `startTime/1000.0` is a double, because `1000.0` forces the result of the division into `double`. You can also specify the type as `double` explicitly, as in the snippet below:

```
-(void)TimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer{
    double startTime=random()%1500+500;
    [timer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:startTime/1000]];
    [controller startCarFromLane:self];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `1000`, since `startTime` is an integral type too, you get integer division. I.e. if `startTime` is less than 1000, that division will yield 0.

With `1000.0`, you get a floating point division, which looks like what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

The .0 makes the value a float instead of an int. When you divide ints, you also get an int; that is, 1/2 = 0. When you divide floats, you get a float, i.e. 1.0/2.0 = 0.5.